# What are those m' and s' preceeding words?

Tags: pronoms, élision

Sorry this must be totally noob question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere. Are they prefixes or short form for something? What difference it makes to add or remove them? Like in the words ***m'importe*** and ***s'écroule***.

I am adding the morphology tag, but I am not even sure it is about morphology or grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> s’écroule

Is from the pronominal verb *s’écrouler*, in fact we should say *se écrouler*, like in *se faire*, *se donner*.

But because *écrouler* starts with a vowel, the prononciation is pretty hard, that's why *se* is shortened to *s'*.

> m'importe

This is in fact a shorter version of *importer à moi*, which became *me importer*, and for the prononciation became *m'importer*

Comment: You will see the same phenomenon with “te” too e.g. *je t’aime.* Just a contraction! Also “ne” and “le/la.”

Comment: Also *de* and *que* now that I think of it. Also *ce*, as in *c'est*. All these have different grammatical situations but the principal is the same, that of contracting with a subsequent word that starts with a vowel.